# MySQL - Use last inserted id on multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, loops

So I want to import some data from a database to another and it goes like this:

```
ID, title, content
```

for the first table, which I can export fine, but the ID is auto_increment, and I want the new database to have their unique IDs, not copied by the insert.
Thing is those posts have a category, which is:

```
post, category
```

Where post is posts.ID. Now, what I want to do is this:

```
INSERT INTO new_db.posts (title, content) VALUES SELECT db1.title, db1.content FROM old_db.posts db1
```

But I want each of those to get their respective category from the categories table.
I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself, I hope so.
Thanks!

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: INSERT INTO new_db.posts (title, content) SELECT db1.title, db1.content FROM old_db.posts db1

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said where the category column is going, but if it is in the same table you can do:

```
INSERT INTO new_db.posts (title, content, category) 
SELECT db1.title, db1.content, c.category 
FROM old_db.posts db1, old_db.categories c 
WHERE db1.ID = c.post
```

If you are going to have a new `ID` which is auto incremented then you are going to need to get the result (ID) of the initial `INSERT` and use it for a new `INSERT` in the categories table.

Comment: It's another table, like I said, post (referencing posts.ID) and category.